# VBA add-in: How to run code on "enabled"

Tags: vba, excel

I am writing an add-in for Excel 2003, using VBA.

I have an Auto_Open subroutine, which automatically runs some code (setting up menus, etc) whenever the add-in is Opened as a file.

What subroutine name (or other logic) do I need to use in order to have code that automatically runs when the add-in is "Enabled" through Excel's Add-in manager?  (And, relatedly, when it is Disabled)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Auto_Open and Auto_Close will do what you want.  Checking the addin in the Addins dialog opens it, and unchecking it closes it.

Comment: According to Excel's VB Help, addins don't automatically close when they are uninstalled.

Comment: I took enabled/disabled to mean checked/unchecked.

Comment: My mileage varies with Auto_Open firing when the add-in starts up, but I guess I will have to go back and see whether it's my fault or an obscure bug.

Comment: Auto_Open and Auto_Close are for backwards compatibility. You should be using Workbook_Open and Workbook_BeforeClose.

Comment: I also use Open and Before_Close events.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the **Workbook_AddinInstall** Event.

From Excel's VB Help, this event:

> Occurs when the workbook is installed as an add-in

Ex:

```
Private Sub Workbook_AddinInstall()
  MsgBox "This workbook was installed as an addin."
End Sub
```

The **Workbook_AddinUninstall** Event fires when the workbook is uninstalled.